# Arranged/ordered checkbox for a one-to-many relationship in CoreData

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

In Xcode's data model inspector, when a relationship is selected, there is checkbox a between labels "Arranged" and "Ordered". CoreData works with sets, so what exactly does it mean in this context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iOS 5 and later allows to have ordered to-many relationships. We've been using Core Data for a while and this is a much needed addition (as we have to support iOS 4, we're still stuck with adding a second number column for 'sortPosition'). Try turning it on, create a subclass and see what kind of code it generates for you. I suspect an NSArray, but haven't tried myself yet.

Comment: It generates properties using `NSOrderedSet` and also generates some more helper methods to do things like insert items at specific indices - but I'm trying to figure out how to specify the sort descriptors to use when you access it by the property; If you have to make a separate fetch-request then it seems fairly pointless.